# Disable gridview cell editing with RepositoryItemTextEdit

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm trying to disable editing for specific gridview cells.

I'm using a RepositoryItemTextEdit with the following properites:

```
     repositoryItemTextEdit.AllowFocused = false;

     m_repositoryItemTextEdit.ReadOnly = true;
```

However i can still click the cell and the edit cursor is present even if i can't change the value.

Is there a way o get rid of the text cursor?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want users to be able to select individual cells, or only full rows? If yes, you can change the SelectionMode to FullRowSelect

Comment: individual cells. i have different repositoryItem on cells.

Comment: are you using devexpress controls?

Answer (score 1):

I got a same problem the cell and the edit cursor is present while after disabled.

And i got the solution.

```
private void tree_ShowingEditor(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Nodes.PromptNode promptNode = tree.FocusedNode as Nodes.PromptNode;

        if (tree.FocusedColumn == valueColumn && promptNode.PromptResult.ValueType.MyValueType == ValueType.ValueTypeOptions.Calculated)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

    }
```

Using `ShowingEditor` event to cancelled this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to handle the `ShownEditor` Event of the GridView.  In there, you test the focused row and column and if the cell should be readonly, you do:

```
grdView.ActiveEditor.Properties.ReadOnly = True
```

To make things nice and understanable for the user, you can also handle the `CustomDrawCell` Event, and set the background color (e.Appearance) to the color used for your readonly controls.

This might be somewhat besides the point, since it doesn't get rid of the cursor; but I don't see what that would be useful.